# In CoffeeScript, how do you pass a function as an argument of a function, which also in turn takes an argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I don't know how to phrase it properly so I can't find answers by Google, but here's basically my problem:

I want my CoffeeScript to output something like this in JS: (I'm developing a Node app)

```
var someapp = require('someapp')
var another = require('another')

someapp.configure(function() {
    someapp.use(another.do('argument'));
});
```

So I wrote it this way in CoffeeScript:

```
someapp = require 'someapp'
another = require 'another'

someapp.configure () ->
    someapp.use another.do 'argument'
```

But instead, I'm getting this output:

```
some.configure(function() {
    return someapp.use(another["do"]('argument'));
});
```

Obviously, my biggest problem is the line `return someapp.use(another["do"]('argument'));` I can't find in the CoffeeScript docs or elsewhere the proper syntax, so I'm hoping someone can point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with your output? I think it is equivalent. another.do == another["do"]

Comment: `do` is a reserved word (and a keyword). It's the normal behavior.

Comment: I am under the impression that `another.do` is different from `another["do"]` ... is it? Sorry, I'm not an expert in Javascript syntactics, but I thought that `another.do` for example, refers to a function in the `another` class while `another["do"]` refers to a particular value in the `another` array with `do` as key. Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: @KixPanganiban in this case, the function `another.do` is an object property that happens to be a function. It can be accessed by using both `another.do()` and `another["do"]()`.

Comment: @Aliou Wow, you're right! Today, I was reminded that everything in JS is in fact objects, so an object property can be accessed just the same as a function. Mind = blown. Wasted hours on this single roadblock alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://coffeescript.org),

> CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

So, coffeescript outputs `another["do"]` to avoid using the `do` reserved keyword.

Furthermore, in this case, the function `another.do` is an object property that happens to be a function. It can be accessed by using both `another.do()` and `another["do"]()`.

Comment: Hmm, I used `do` as a function, forgetting that it is a reserved keyword. Assuming that instead of `do`, I'm using, say, `happy`, it still outputs `another["happy"]` instead of `another.happy` which I am expecting.

Comment: @KixPanganiban For some reason, Coffeescript seems to output accessed object property by using the `[]` notation instead of the dot notation. It is maybe to differentiate from object methods, which you can only call with the dot notation, I think.